# Google AutocompleteService doesn't return results for certain cities

Tags: javascript, angular, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-api

I'm developing Angular 6 application

I found out the Google Autocomplete doesn't return proper values for valid inputs.

When i call API for certain cities it returns ZERO_RESULTS, or just ignore calling a function telling me about specifing an input.

**Those are the cities:**

> Niš, Nisko, Görlitz

Even though it works for other places.

Here's my code:

```
        const firstResult = $('.pac-container .pac-item:first').text(); //returns 'NiskoPolska' 
        console.log(firstResult);
        const autoCompleteService = new google.maps.places.AutocompleteService();
        const placesService = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(self.searchPlacesRef.nativeElement);

        autoCompleteService.getPlacePredictions({ input: firstResult }, function (results, status) {
          if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
            placesService.getDetails({ placeId: results[0].place_id }, function (result, stat) {
              if (stat == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
               console.log(result);
              }
            });
          }
        });
```

Could someone tell me what's the reason it doesn't work for some cities?

Comment: I am commenting because I am curious about this too. I always figured that it was because I either had a free key, or that the google maps api chose to cut lesser known cities for optimization purposes.

Comment: So you say it returns `ZERO_RESULTS` **and** you say it returns `NiskoPolska` when you search for `nisko`. So **what you search for** and **what is returned** is unclear from your question.

Comment: @MrUpsidown  I meant that this jquery returns it. `const firstResult = $('.pac-container .pac-item:first').text();`. Sorry i edited question to make it looks more clear.

Comment: [Görlitz](https://www.google.com/maps/place/G%C3%B6rlitz,+Germany/@51.1061219,14.9672012,13.03z/data=!4m8!1m2!2m1!1zTmnFoSwgTmlza28sIEfDtnJsaXR6!3m4!1s0x4708dc31a78fee7f:0x5e9effc1a38b3b57!8m2!3d51.150494!4d14.9688721) seems to be locality in Germany. Would you mind explaining what is Niš and Nisko in this address?

Comment: @xomena Niš is one of the biggest Serbian cities, Nisko is small city in Poland. Those are 3 different cities I found those are lacking results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see that you are using a Place autocomplete service from Google Maps JavaScript API. You use only `input` parameter, that means you are searching globally and without applying any type filter. When you search globally only most prominent features that match your text will be returned. For example, if you search 'Niš' as shown in my example https://jsfiddle.net/xomena/xqLk0atz/ you will get following predictions

[image]

If your intention is search only cities you can add types filter in autocomplete request as shown in https://jsfiddle.net/xomena/2qs53dgx/. In this case you will get the following predictions globally

[image]

As you can see this time Niš is a second prediction, but your code relies only on the first result from this list. That is not correct assumption in my opinion. Nisku might be more prominent on global level, so you shouldn't expect that Niš appears as the first element.

You can improve a bit the results list if you provide an area bias in your autocomplete request. For example if you are interested in European cities, let bias results to Europe adding location and radius parameters. I did it in https://jsfiddle.net/xomena/rmsLvgyx/. This time Niš is a first prediction that might work correctly with your code.

[image]

Here is my last code snippet that shows Niš as a first prediction

```js
function initService() {
  var displaySuggestions = function(predictions, status) {
    if (status != google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
      alert(status);
      return;
    }

    predictions.forEach(function(prediction) {
      var li = document.createElement('li');
      var icon_url = "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/geocode-71.png"; 

      var icon = document.createElement("IMG");
      icon.src = icon_url;
      icon.width = 24;
      icon.height = 24;
      li.appendChild(icon);
      li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(prediction.description));
      document.getElementById('results').appendChild(li);
    });
  };

  var service = new google.maps.places.AutocompleteService();
  service.getPlacePredictions({ 
    input: 'Niš',
    types: ['(cities)'],
    location: new google.maps.LatLng(49.18004,13.554544),
    radius: 1000000
  }, displaySuggestions);
}
```

```css
#map {
  height: 100%;
}
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#right-panel {
  font-family: 'Roboto','sans-serif';
  line-height: 30px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

#right-panel select, #right-panel input {
  font-size: 15px;
}

#right-panel select {
  width: 100%;
}

#right-panel i {
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<div id="right-panel">
  <p>Query suggestions for 'Niš':</p>
  <ul id="results"></ul>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDztlrk_3CnzGHo7CFvLFqE_2bUKEq1JEU&libraries=places&callback=initService"
        async defer></script>
```

I hope these examples explain how autocomplete service works and how important is a view port bias for this service.

Comment: Great response. However I cannot apply it to my business logic. User should be able to search location using street name or even his favourite coffee shop.

Comment: In this case the only reliable method is providing location biasing if this is possible.

Comment: I added geographical location bias and indeed it helped. Now it's working. Many thanks